# app from android studio keeps crashing on my phone

Tags: java, android

This is my first attempt on android studio and I have followed a tutorial where I implement a QR scanner.

**EDIT:**
When I run the app on my phone, I manage to start it just fine, but when I press the "SCAN QR CODE" button, the app crashes and the crash window says "app keeps stopping".

when I push the button, it is supposed to allow the phone to scan a qr code that will get a name and address which is assigned to the qr code and print them out on the app.

This is the code and the error message. The library I used is the zxing library.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.androidscanner2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewName, textViewAddress;

    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewAddress= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);

        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    }

    public void scanQRCode(View view) {
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    textViewName.setText(obj.getString("name"));
                    textViewAddress.setText(obj.getString("address"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}

**build.gradle:**


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.androidscanner2"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

**////////////////////////ERROR/////////////////////////////**

```
Error:

E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:942)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                ... 6 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.example.androidscanner2-xGuLTVtPV8DLGniMH_oh_Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:676)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:709)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:942)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                ... 6 more
Application terminated.
```

Comment: DOn't post an image of your error, Copy past the text.  Anyone over the age of 30 or so can't help you because they can't read that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forget to include the zxing core in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
```